# C# MVC ActionLink clear session before reloading page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, actionlink

I have a simple form page, where user can fill some data. After I press post, I need all that data to remain as it is, so if user wants to change data, he/she can. After I save data I store `Client` object in `Session` and every time I press Save button, I check if there is user already in `Session`.

Now I have `@Html.ActionLink("New client", "NewUser");`, that I press, when I want to create new user. So this link would reload the page and clear that `Session`.

Note that `"New user"` should redirect to `Index` instead, but I managed to get it to work like that, but is not valid way to do so.

Controller code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(_vm);
}

public ActionResult NewUser()
{
     Session["newClient"] = null;
     return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clearing the `session` can only done on backend so you have to make action to clear the session but you dont need `return RedirectToAction("Index");` instead return the view

```
public ActionResult NewUser()
{
     Session["newClient"] = null;
     return View("Index",_vm);
}
```

since you are `redirecting` to the `index` view for creating new user

Comment: This navigates me to `/Home/NewUser` and when I try to save my form there, then it doesn't trigger my `Index [HttpPost]` method anymore, but rather `NewUser()` method.

Comment: because by default it will submit the form to the same action which returned the view so you can specify action with  `Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home")`